# How can you find the id of a custom potion in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been trying to figure out how to use the sign shop plugin to sell potions with custom effects. I know how to use the sign shop plugin, I just need to know how to find the id of a potion with custom effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of all status effect IDs, the potions use the same IDs:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_data_values#Status_effects ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Java_Edition_data_values&oldid=1194946#Status_effects))

---

You can also take a potion out of the Creative inventory, throw it on the ground and execute the command

```
/entitydata @e[type=item,c=1] {}
```

The chat output will tell you all NBT data of that potion, in case you don't know what tags you need or where to put them.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, accept the answer so Fabian is rewarded the deserved points.